# using the "ScanOperator.In" for DynamoDB in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using the [AWS SDK for .NET](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/), and I'm trying to perform a "scan" operation using the "in" operator.

The ScanCondition takes in three arguments, but I'm not sure what the last argument [the values] should be.

- Is it an array of strings? (this returns empty, when it should return results)
- Is it a comma-delimited list of strings? (this throws an error saying it could not convert a list of strings into a string)

I've tried a number of different things, and nothing has worked.

```
public void GetUsers()
{
    AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient("key", "secret", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("systemEndpoint");
    DynamoDBContext context = new DynamoDBContext(client);

    var results = context.Scan<User>(new ScanCondition("ID", ScanOperator.In, list /* what goes here? */));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The *values* argument should be of type object[].

In your example, (assuming your list is of type int[] or List), it needs to be cast to type object[] first.

```
var objectValues = list.Select(x => (object)x).ToArray();
var results = context.Scan<User>(new ScanCondition("ID", ScanOperator.In, objectValues));
```

It's a [known](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/345#issuecomment-218217312) usability issue with the API. If your ID property were of type string, it would work as you'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/T_Amazon_DynamoDBv2_Model_Condition_NET4_5.html) states the object needed is [AttributeValueList](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/P_Amazon_DynamoDBv2_Model_Condition_AttributeValueList_NET4_5.html).
So you will need to wrap your strings as [AttributeValue](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/T_Amazon_DynamoDBv2_Model_AttributeValue_NET4_5.html)s before passing them to the `Scan` command